# A new equivalent characterization of Riemann-Integrability

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

**Question:**

Given two bounded functions $\,f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R\;$ and $\;\theta:(0,b-a]\to [0,1]$.

Suppose $\,P:a=x_0<x_1<⋯<x_n=b\;$ is a partition of $[a,b]$.

Let $\,Δx_k=x_k−x_{k−1}$ and $\;‖P‖=\max_{1≤k≤n}\,Δx_k$.

If $$\exists A\in\mathbb R,\,\forall\epsilon>0,\,\exists\delta>0:\,\forall P\;\bigl(‖P‖<\delta\bigl)\;\Longrightarrow \,\Biggl\vert{\sum_{k=1}^n f\bigl(x_{k−1}+\theta(Δx_k)Δx_k\bigl)Δx_k-A}\Biggl\vert<\epsilon\,,$$

i.e. $$\sum_{k=1}^n f\bigl(x_{k−1}+\theta(Δx_k)Δx_k\bigl)Δx_k\to A\; \bigl(‖P‖\to 0\bigl)\,,$$

then can we always conclude that $\,f\;$ is Riemann-integrable?

**Background:**

I notice that Kristensen, Poulsen and Reich (A characterization of Riemann-Integrability, The American Mathematical Monthly, vol.69, No.6, pp. 498-505) have proved a similar result with the Darboux property, but my question need not satisfy Darboux property.

Can anybody help me? Any hints or solution would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your thoughts? What if $\theta \equiv 0$?

Comment: As I know, the case that $\theta\equiv 0$ has been proved by Kristensen, Poulsen and Reich (A characterization of Riemann-Integrability, The American Mathematical Monthly, vol.69, No.6, pp. 498-505).

Comment: If there is some function $\theta : (0,1] \to [0,1]$ so that $x+\theta(y-x)y \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ for each $x < y$ in $[0,1]$, then the answer is no (by considering the function $f = 1_\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: So can you concretely construct this function?

Comment: I can't. I'm not sure if it exists, but I think it does...

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think this function exists. For example, fix $y-x=1/2$ and let $x$ range from $0$ to $1/2$, then we can always find a certain $x$ such that $x+\theta(1/2)/2\,\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I'm confused. If you plug in $y=x+1/2$, you get $x+\theta(1/2)(x+1/2)$, not $x+\theta(1/2)1/2$.

Comment: Because it is $\,x_{k-1}+\theta(\Delta x_k)\Delta x_k\,$ that appears in my original question, not $\,x_{k-1}+\theta(\Delta x_k) x_k\,$.

Comment: oh you're right. though you should've said that the function in my comment should have been different rather than saying "I dont think this function exists" and then talking about a different function

Comment: OK. Thanks for your attention and comments.